# How do you *tag* a partition as ext4?

Tags: mount, ext3, ext4

I have an ext3 partition so when I do this:

```
mount /dev/blah /mnt/blah
```

it is mounted automatically as ext3. I can get it to mount as ext4 by running

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/blah /mnt/blah
```

and it works. I presume the partition is somehow tagged as being ext3. Is it possible to change that to ext4 so that:

```
mount /dev/blah /mnt/blah
```

will mount it as ext4. This is for an experiment. I want to do it without enabling the new features in ext4 so I can go back to ext3.

Comment: Which distro? `mount -V`? Did you get the "You must specify the filesystem type" message when mouting without `-t`? `cat /proc/filesystems`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If at creation time the file system did not use, or explicitly disabled, the ext4 extensions (like `uninit_bg` and `flex_bg`), the filesystem will be actually ext3 (if it has journal) or ext2(if it has not ext3 or ext4 features).

You can enable the ext4 features with `tune2fs -O`.

ext4 man page:

> If the -O option is used to explicitly add or remove filesystem options that should be set in the newly created filesystem,
>   the resulting filesystem may not be
>                 supported  by the requested fs-type.  (e.g., "mke2fs -t ext3 -O extents /dev/sdXX" will create a filesystem that is not
>   supported by the ext3 implementation as
>                 found in the Linux kernel; and "mke2fs -t ext3 -O ^has_journal /dev/hdXX" will create a filesystem that does not have a
>   journal and hence will not be supported
>                 by the ext3 filesystem code in the Linux kernel.)

tune2fs man page:

> -O [^]feature[,...]-O [^]feature[,...]
>
> Enabling certain  filesystem  features  may  prevent  the
>                 filesystem  from being mounted by kernels which do not support those features.  In particular the uninit_bg and flex_bg
>   features are only supported by the ext4
>                 filesystem.

Comment: For the record, just adding extents caused the partition to be recognized as ext4 at boot time. Enabling uninit_bg made it recognizable as ext4 by mount, but at boot time it would try to mount it as ext3 and failed. I'm not sure if this is true for every machine out there.

Answer (score 0):

[**`man mount`**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount):

> If  no  `-t`  option  is given, or if the auto type is specified, mount
>   will try to guess the desired type.  Mount
>                 uses the `blkid` library for guessing the filesystem type; if that does not turn up anything that looks  familiar,
>                 mount  will  try  to  read the file `/etc/filesystems`, or, if that does not exist, `/proc/filesystems`.  All of the
>                 filesystem types listed there will be tried, except for those that are labeled "nodev" (e.g., devpts,  proc  and
>                 nfs).  If `/etc/filesystems ends` in a line with a single * only, mount will read `/proc/filesystems` afterwards.

```
# mount -V
mount from util-linux-ng 2.17.2 (with libblkid and selinux support)
```

Besides the `blk_id`:

```
# blkid -o value -s TYPE /dev/sdb1
ext4
```

there are some other ways to determine the filesystem of an unmounted partition:

```
# file -s /dev/sdb1 
/dev/sdb1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data (extents) (large files) (huge files)

# fsck -N /dev/sdb1
fsck from util-linux-ng 2.17.2
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sdb1] fsck.ext4 /dev/sdb1 

# parted /dev/sdb1 print
Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/sdb1: 107GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  107GB  107GB  ext4
```

Answer (score -2):

`mount /dev/blah /mnt/blah` works only with an fstab entry, doesn't it? So change the fstab entry to ext4 and that's it.

What you probably mean is the behaviour of

```
mount -t auto /dev/blah /mnt/blah
```

I don't know where the order in which ext3 and ext4 are checked is defined. I believe there is no mark in the FS itself: "Prefer to be mounted as ext4." Something similar to a mark are non backward compatible ext4 features which are set in the superblock. These would prevent the FS from being mounted as ext3 but that's not what you want.